# Using a WP filter makes a value disappear?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter

I'm using [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/latest-tweets-widget/) to display some tweets.

After using the override filters as shown [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/latest-tweets-widget/other_notes/), it makes the timestamp that naturally occurs to disappear.

The author gives us an example that you can use to override the default markup like so:

```
add_filter('latest_tweets_render_tweet', function( $html, $date, $link, array $tweet ){
    $pic = $tweet['user']['profile_image_url_https'];
    return '<p class="my-tweet"><img src="'.$pic.'"/>'.$html.'</p><p class="my-date"><a href="'.$link.'">'.$date.'</a></p>';
}, 10, 4 );
```

Here is my version:

```
add_filter('latest_tweets_render_tweet', function($html){
return
'<div class="row">
    <div class="small-1 columns twitter-icon-wrap">
      <i class="fa fa-twitter tweet-icon fa-2x fa-pull-left"></i>
    </div>
  <div class="small-11 columns tweet-wrap">'.$html.'</div>
  <p class="tweet-details"><a href="" target="_blank"></a></p>
</div>';
}, 10 , 1 );
```

If I add `$date` after the `$html` variable in the function like:

```
add_filter('latest_tweets_render_tweet', function($html, $date)
```

I then get a warning:

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for ******\******\Extras\{closure}(), called in /srv/www/*********/current/web/wp/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 235 and defined in /srv/www/*******/current/web/app/themes/*********/lib/extras.php on line 144
```

line 144 is `add_filter('latest_tweets_render_tweet', function($html)`

If I subsequently add the `$date` variable into the returned HTML ignorning the warning, I then get an error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: date in.....
```

Although it's a warning, there is still no date displayed. How can I make the date re-appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the final argument in `add_filter()` (`1`). This parameter is the [number of accepted arguments](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/).

```
add_filter ( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )
```

Since you want to use 2 arguments, you need to change the final argument of `add_filter()` to `2`. In other words:

```
add_filter ( 'latest_tweets_render_tweet', function( $html, $date ) {}, 10, 2 );
```

It's unclear what exactly you're trying to do with `$date`...so I'll just give you a generic example:

```
add_filter('latest_tweets_render_tweet', function( $html, $date ){
    // $html and $date are now available to you
    return true;  // remember to return something (likely something different than this)
}, 10, 2 );  // <-- This argument is changed to 2
```

Comment: Yes I have attempted that but then I get an error saying $date is undefined as stated above. I'm basically trying to get the timestamp to re-appear as for some reason, with the add_filter('latest_tweets_render_tweet'); it removes it.

Comment: @AshleyBrown That's not possible. Please edit your question and share the actual code that's throwing the error.

Comment: Please share the entire filter. It's still unclear what code you're using to produce the error.

Comment: It seems that you didn't read my entire answer. I edited to clarify. You need to also change the final argument of `add_filter()` from `10, 1` to `10, 2`. `2` represents the number of arguments your filter function will accept.

Comment: Oh I didn't understand at first, now I do. This is my first time using filters and that has fixed it. Just for an understanding, why is this required? Is it a security feature to stop a type of injection to specify the amount of args? I'd have thought this wasn't needed, it usually isn't in vanilla PHP from my understanding?

Comment: By default, only the first parameter will be passed to the callable (if you leave off the `$accepted_args`, the default number is `1`). You need to explicitly state when you're using more than one. I hope this makes sense.  This is one of those old "why are things this way???" parts of WordPress.